# Calculate the intensities of the following circuit, using the node voltage method

Tags: dc

[image]

Is2=3A;
E1=27V;
E3=18V;
E4=36V;
R3=R4=R5=3 Ohms.

Let 0 be the grounded node.

I tried applying the equations:

G1: 1/R3= 1/3 S

G2: 1/R5+ 1/R4 = 2/3 S

G12: Infinite

The resistance of the wire with the E1 voltage source is 0 (ideal wire) , so its conductance is infinite. How can I apply the method ?

Comment: Have you tried to write out your nodal equations, this sounds like home work. If you have someone might be able to quickly spot your mistake, otherwise homework questions with no attemp at solving are usually closed.

Answer (score 1):

I will rearrange the circuit so it might be easier to visualize what needs done, but without you first attempting to solve this, I won't provide any solid answers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEoj4x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I also presume you are referring to the "node voltage method" [described here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/node-voltage-method/), which involves converting voltage sources with series resistance to current sources with parallel resistance. I personally don't like this solution method; however, you need to learn to solve circuits in a variety of ways. If you are good at one method over another, you can always solve the circuit in different ways to check your work.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have solved this circuit before using other methods. When I asked this question, I got stuck because I had the infinite conductance in two equations. I tried a few more times, and moved the ground to node "1", managing to get some equations, but currents are different than the ones I obtained. I will post my attempt here:

Comment: Note: Ground on node 1; Method 1) Using conductance: G00 = 2/3 S, G20=2/3 S, G00=1S; I get V0=15V and V2=-E1=-27V. Then I calculate currents using pottential differences divided by resistances._________________Method 2) Using Kirchhoff 1st law for every node, then finding voltages V0 and V2 using two equations, I get different results. Sorry for bad formatting.